# People Search in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, people-search

I am curious if this is the default behavior for people search in SharePoint 2013.
Scenario: When searching for first name and the first letter of the last name we get no result, but if we type in first name and first letter of the last name then a wild card character we get result.

Search Term: Jon D
Result: no results

Search Term: Jon D*
Result: we get results

Comment: This is how the Search in SharePoint work. OOTB you can't search for half words. Only whole words or by using a wildcard is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.

You could modify the search result webpart to automatically append the * at the end. Not ideal for document search, but for people search its okay.