# Sharepoint 2013 - people search configuration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, people-search

I have not configured the search but I need to change it (perhaps understand more about it). The users are imported from AD in User Profile Service Application.

We use the people search as a directory to locate staff, phone numbers etc.

The issue is that when I run searches for the name Peter - if I type in "Pet" the first three characters of the name it does not return any staff named Peter (and yes - many staff by this name) but does return a staff member named "Pat".

I am not sure why it does this for starters - but I would like to change it so that it does return the results for staff by using the method of typing in the first few characters of a name.

Comment: I believe this search query is using fuzzy matching. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Try typing Pet* in the search

Comment: You can change and add to the "nickname" list on-prem. That will help the matching.

Answer (score 1):

For wildcard people search, we can edit the search result web part in the people search page and add the query below.

{searchboxquery}*

There are a similar post:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e5dbdf0-415d-4c6b-b172-669da0a1846f/wildcard-search-on-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointsearch

[People Search in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117470/people-search-in-sharepoint-2013)